# mssql display 1 decimal point if available, else show none

Tags: sql-server, decimal-point

Simple one I think.

I have a query that shows lengths of items.

Query:

```
select length from vw_OutstandingVsInStock1 OVI
LEFT JOIN Departments DEP
on OVI.Department COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=DEP.Description
where OutstandingVolume>0.39
```

This returns results like:

```
0.9
1.2
1.5
1.8
2.1
2.4
2.7
3.0
3.3
3.6...
```

In the case of `3.0` I want it to display as `3`

so if no decimal value, show `int` with no decimals. if a decimal exists show decimal to 1 decimal point?

so desired output is `3` and `6` instead of `3.0` and `6.0`

I am using MSSQL 2012.

Comment: the server does not show anything - it just returns binary 8-bytes `double` aka `long float` value. It is some another program which renders this number onto the screen or onto the paper. And what the program is that you did not tell...

Comment: Hi, am using an mssql query window in management studio 2012? the length comes field comes from a view. Thanks.

Comment: What about rounding? Do you just want to get one decimal digit and disregard the rest or do you want the decimal to round up or down if needed? Or can there never be more than one decimal digit?

Comment: Thanks, never more than 1 digit so no rounding. id a digit show it, else just the integer. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another variant ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5424))

```
;WITH vw_OutstandingVsInStock1 (length)
     AS (SELECT 0.9 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1.2 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1.5 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1.8 UNION ALL
         SELECT 2.1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 2.4 UNION ALL
         SELECT 2.7 UNION ALL
         SELECT 3.0 UNION ALL
         SELECT 3.3 UNION ALL
         SELECT 3.6)
SELECT IIF(length % 1 = 0,
           CAST(length AS INT),
           CAST(length AS SQL_VARIANT))
FROM   vw_OutstandingVsInStock1
```

Comment: @sajjan Just replace iif with a case expression. The rest works the same.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
select cast(length as float) from vw_OutstandingVsInStock1 OVI
...
```

Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of anything cleaner than this at the moment. I've placed the literal values in a CTE, you would place your existing query there:

```
;With rowss(length) as (
select 0.9 union all select 1.2 union all select 1.5 union all select
       1.8 union all select 2.1 union all select 2.4 union all select
       2.7 union all select 3.0 union all select 3.3 union all select
       3.6
)
select
    STUFF(stLength,CHARINDEX('.',stLength),
        CASE WHEN stLength like '%.0' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END,'')
from
    (select CONVERT(varchar(10),length) as stLength from rowss) t
```

The trick is to use `STUFF` and to decide, based on how the string ends, to either delete 2 characters or do nothing.

Result:

```
0.9
1.2
1.5
1.8
2.1
2.4
2.7
3
3.3
3.6
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN RIGHT(length,1) = 0 THEN STUFF(length, LEN(length)-1, 2, '') 
  ELSE STUFF(length, LEN(length), 0, '') 
  END
```

I assumed the length has data type numeric(?,1).