# Decimal Place issue when use union all Concept

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 1.233
UNION ALL
SELECT 333
```

I am getting output as:

```
1.233
333.000
```

But i don't want to that extra decimal place. I need output as:

```
1.233
333.
```

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mssql display 1 decimal point if available, else show none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568354/mssql-display-1-decimal-point-if-available-else-show-none)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT CAST(1.233 AS FLOAT)
UNION ALL
SELECT 333
```

Comment: Ok Flicker Bro.. Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need further calculation, you might try converting the columns to a string.

```
SELECT CAST(1.233 AS VARCHAR)
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(333 AS VARCHAR)
```